# Magento 2 how to filter product collection on category page with custom filters

Tags: magento2, category, category-products

I have one category in system... For example EMT. There are many products assigned to it. Now I want to filter some products for particular customers for that category. I mean only specific products should be display in that category for some customers. It should display all the products to guest users.

How can I do that so all the collection should filter with proper layered navigation and toolbar collection.

Can anyone suggest the way to do this with files I need to override?

[image]

Comment: you have pre list of product to show to customer ?

Comment: you can use event `catalog_block_product_list_collection` to filter you products

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism can you help on this?

Comment: @JagdishBarot any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you know how to write a plugin and how to write a script in Magento 2. With this in mind, the plan to have your issue resolved would be as follows:

1. add a product attribute that is a boolean and define for all your products whether they can be displayed to guests or not
   —> make it layered enabled
2. update all your products in your catalog with a script
3. in the block `\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct`, you may change the function that loads the products using a plugin on the `function getLoadedProductCollection`

Comment: wrong product count in layernavigation.

Answer (score 1):

**app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" type="Vendor\ModuleName\Block\Product\ListProducts" />
    <preference for="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager" type="Vendor\Modulename\Block\Product\Pager" />
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" type="Vendor\Modulename\Block\Product\Toolbar" />
</config>
```

**Vendor\ModuleName\Block\Product\ListProducts.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Block\Product;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context;
use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver;
use Magento\Framework\App\CacheInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Framework\Url\Helper\Data;

class ListProducts extends ListProduct
{
    public $registry;
    public $cache;

    /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface  */
    public $productRepository;
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder  */
    public $searchCriteriaBuilder;
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Api\Search\FilterGroupBuilder  */
    public $filterGroupBuilder;
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder  */
    public $filterBuilder;

    public $collectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\Search\FilterGroupBuilder $filterGroupBuilder,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder $filterBuilder,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        CacheInterface $cache,
        Registry $registry,
        Context $context,
        PostHelper $postDataHelper,
        Resolver $layerResolver,
        CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository,
        Data $urlHelper,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
        $this->filterBuilder = $filterBuilder;
        $this->filterGroupBuilder = $filterGroupBuilder;
        $this->cache = $cache;
        $this->registry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context, $postDataHelper, $layerResolver, $categoryRepository, $urlHelper, $data);
    }

    public function getLoadedProductCollection()
    {
        $collection = parent::getLoadedProductCollection();
        // Add Your Filters
        return $collection;
    }
}
```

**Vendor\ModuleName\Block\Product\Pager.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Block\Product;

class Pager extends \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager
{
    public function getCollection()
    {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $request = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface');
        $field = $request->getParam('field', null);
        $attributeValue = $request->getParam($field);
        $collection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->getCollection();
        // Add the Same Filters here To Override the Count of Products
        return $collection;
    }
}
```

**Vendor\ModuleName\Block\Product\Toolbar.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Block\Product;

class Toolbar extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar
{
    public function getCollection()
    {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $request = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface');
        $field = $request->getParam('field', null);
        $attributeValue = $request->getParam($field);
        $collection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')
                ->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        // Add Same Filter to Override the Paginations
                
        return $collection; 
    }
}
```

In This Way The Products Collection, Product Count, Pagination and the Layered Navigation will be Accurate.